# Removing specific colored edge section of an image using MATLAB

Tags: matlab

How can I remove the purple colored section from the edge of the image but not from inside of the image using MATLAB. Please suggest me a general code which can be applied future for any kind of this type image.

Main Image

[image]

In case you don't get which section is to be removed I marked the section with red color

[image]

Comment: But, the thing is surounded by purple all around. Why just that one?

Comment: sorry for inconvenience. I have to remove all purple surroundings from the image, not just the red marked region. I hope you understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this is what I came with. I hope the code is self explanatory.

There are 2 values you need to play with. One of them is the number in `imdilate`. That one will define "how big the boundary is". Of course that depends on you.

The other one is the value for HSV color segmentation. In HSV, H is color, and purple is around 250-335 range. The problem is that blue is very similar to purple, and the limit between purple and blue is very ambiguous. I used 250 as lower limit in my code, but you may wan to modify that.

If you have any question please ask.

```
% The image is indexed image. Else convert. 
[img,c]=imread('https://i.imgur.com/dxkJSi0.png');

% Get part with color
bwimg=img~=0;

% get only the biggest part
lblimg=bwlabel(bwimg,4);
stat = regionprops(lblimg,'Centroid','Area','PixelIdxList');
[maxValue,index] = max([stat.Area]);

todelete=1:size(stat,1);
todelete(index)=[];
for ii=todelete
    bwimg(stat(ii).PixelIdxList)=0;
end

%update image with without "noise"
img(~bwimg)=0;

% get the contour of the image (thanks @rayryeng)
er = imerode(bwimg, strel('square', 3));
out = imsubtract(bwimg, er);

% we will increase the boundary so we pick a larger region
% Here you need your input. it depedns how much you dilate the image, the
% part of the of the image that will be considered boudnary will increase.
boundary=imdilate(out,strel('square', 10));

% now lets see withc colors are purple. For that we get HSV space. Shades
% of purple are aruond 265~335 H

hsvc=rgb2hsv(c);
purple=find(hsvc(:,1)>250/360&hsvc(:,1)<335/360);


% Get purple in the whole image
purpleimg=zeros(size(img));
for ii=1:size(purple)
    purpleimg(img==purple(ii))=purple(ii);
end
% get locations of purple in the boudnary
purpbound=purpleimg.*boundary~=0;
% delete them from the original image
imgNOpurple=img;
imgNOpurple(purpbound)=0;

% plot results

figure(1)
subplot(221)

imshow(purpleimg,c)
title('purple in the image')
subplot(222)
imshow(purpleimg.*boundary,c);
title('purple boundary')

subplot(223)
imshow(img,c)
title('original image')

subplot(224)
imshow(imgNOpurple,c);
title('Image without purple boundary')
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was very helpful.

Comment: Can you please help me with another problem? I have 100+ images of this type. I want to save all the final images(image without purple boundary) in a folder of my computer in *.tif format. How can I do that? thank you

Comment: @jonsnowknowsnothing if you have another problem ask another question ;). Thus the answer of that has been several times answered around here, so a bit of googleingwill help you!